# First time using blender, can’t get updates from sculpting mode into other modes?

Tags: sculpting

This is my very first project in Blender. I’m trying to do a self portrait.

Everything was fine for a while until I realized that when I switched to other modes, everything I did in sculpting mode doesn’t show in other modes. It’s like the other modes are 10+ steps behind where I am in the project now.

I really do not want to start over and even if I do, I would like to know what not to do next time.

Sculpt mode[image]

Object mode[image]

Comment: Add screenshots. Please, refrain from adding “first time” or “complete noob” in the title (you can mention it in the question), or adding “please help[exhasperated punctuation]” at the end of a question on a site specifically purposed for asking for such help, (makes you sound like a pushover who is panicking).

Comment: Edit Mode > Right Click > Subdivide > Menu Appears on bottom left, cange divisions to 100, or 10 then try and sculpt again.

Comment: Before trying JeremyClarkson2's suggestion, please provide screenshots or a blend file so that we can have a look and see if your sculpt is salvageable. This person has suggested something that might destructively (non-reversibly) change your model. Try it on a copy of the file if you wish, but there may be another solution :)

Comment: It sounds like you might have used the multiresolution modifier in a way that it isn't showing the detail in the other modes, but I couldn't say for sure without seeing some more details of especially the modifier stack on the object in question.  As others have suggested, screenshots or sharing a blend file especially would be really helpful here please.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.